# I am trying to test a relationship with Inspection and Defect using Django and got an error in tests.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do a fun project that relates Inspections and Defects.
The error I got was Inspection() got an unexpected keyword argument partNum.  Here is my urls.py.

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.urls import resolve
from django.test import TestCase
from .views import home,inspection_defects
from .models import Inspection

# Create your tests here.

class HomeTests(TestCase):
    def test_home_view_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('home')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_home_url_resolves_home_view(self):
        view = resolve('/')
        self.assertEquals(view.func, home)

class InspectionDefectTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Inspection.objects.create(workOrderNum='312456',partNum='SD33345100-AQ1',customerName='TERRA Inc.',qtyInspected=10,qtyRejected=2)

    def test_inspection_defects_view_success_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('inspection_defects', kwargs={'pk': 1})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

Here is my urls.py file.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from finalreports import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^inspections/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.inspection_defects, name='inspection_defects'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here's views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Inspection

# Create your views here.

def home(request):

    inspections = Inspection.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'inspections': inspections})

def inspection_defects(request, pk):
    inspection = Inspection.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'topics.html', {'inspection': inspection})
```

Here's topics.html

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ inspection.workOrderNum }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">Inspections</li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">{{ inspection.workOrderNum }}</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, Django is complaining that the test.py is failing due to an unexpected keyword argument partNum.

I don't know where to look for the problem.  It's getting frustrated thinking about programming all the time.

The error is Inspection() got an unexpected keyword argument partNum and I don't know where to look for the error.

Comment: I followed the tutorial on https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/18/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-3.html#list-of-useful-url-patterns but I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In tests.py play with this instead.

```
class InspectionTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        Inspection.objects.create(workOrderNum='123DER', partNumber='sd', customerName="RYANTRONICS", qtyInspected=10, qtyRejected=3)

    def test_board_topics_view_success_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('inspection_topics', kwargs={'pk': 1})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

It's good to keep trying and take your time.  After all, a fun project should not be rushed.

The hardest thing in Django is getting the URLs to work.